# jQuery animations lag and jam

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, lag, singlepage

I'm working on this single-page site, few things (h1 opacity, nav height, etc) are animated based on scrolling. Initially it works, but after scrolling around a bit, heavy lag and unexpexted behaviour is experienced (eg. non-stop toggling of nav height for a few seconds). Tried velocity.js and transit.js, same thing happens. I've made this simplified pen to demonstrate:

http://codepen.io/galingong/pen/BHeyz/

Am I doing something wrong or is this a browser issue?I'm testing in Chrome 35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use `stop()` before animation. This problem is happenning cause all your animation are queued after each other, and this queue get longer with each animatio. Using `stop()` ensure to stop all previous animation for specific element & starting from new point.

E.g.

```
$('header h1').animate({opacity:0},300);
```

change to

```
$('header h1').stop().animate({opacity:0},300);
```

Answer (score 2):

The scroll event is fired *lots* of times on every scroll, so it can be a major performance bottleneck. You need to be very careful about what you do in the handler on the scroll event. John Resig has some [good advice](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter) which I would summarize as:

- Cache your jQuery selectors
- Have as few scroll handlers as possible
- Limit how often you call your handler

Here's a re-write of your scroll function following his suggestions: [**Working Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EIzgD?editors=001)

```
$(function(){
  var lastScroll = 0,
      $window = $(window),
      $nav = $('nav'),
      $h1 = $('header h1'),
      lastScroll = 0.
      didScroll = false
  ;

  $window.scroll(function(){
    didScroll = true;
  });

  window.setInterval(function() {
    if(didScroll) {
      didScroll = false;
      onScroll();
    }
  }, 250);

  function onScroll() {
    var st = $window.scrollTop();

    if (st > lastScroll){
      $nav.stop().animate({paddingTop:"0px"},300);
    }
    else {
      $nav.stop().animate({paddingTop:"100"},300);
    }

    if (st >= 300){
      $h1.stop().animate({opacity:0},300);
    }
    else{
      $h1.stop().animate({opacity:1},300);
    }

    lastScroll = st;
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks, although the suggestion rohanAM made solved my problem, I'll definitely read the post you've linked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, before .animate() you should use .stop() in most cases. 
This method stops all effect which have connection with current element, because if hover more quickly on element thant it has animate property - duration, all behavior stay in some order. And jQuery is going to complete all order.

Comment: Does this apply also when using velocity.js or transit.js?

Comment: .stop() - is method jQuery, if velocity or transit works as jquery object or on jquery, so it will work. You should to try and play with it, it is very simple method you see.

Comment: Velocity's stop command is used via $element.velocity("stop"). You can also do $element.velocity("stop", true) to clear the entire remaining animation queue.